# Yahoo Axis Browser supports the HTML 5 ,CSS 3 and Flash in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, yahoo

Recently Yahoo released an browser for the Apple mobiles and extensions for chrome and mozilla etc browsers. Axis can play the flash and html css animations??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube videos are displayed w/ HTML5 (QuickTime), and no, the browser don't display flash, it shows the same message using safari (To download flash player).